# Path on Ubuntu server in java?

Tags: java, server, path

I just did a little project in java, packed the .jar and application.properties to my VPS and wanted to test it there. The tool reads logfiles.

I specified the path to the logfile within the application.properties as follows:

```
LOGPATH=/folder1/folder2/logs/thelogIwant.log
```

The path is parsed as follows:

```
  public String makePath(String path) {


    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;


    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("application.properties");
        prop.load(input);


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return  prop.getProperty(path);
}
    Path logFile = Paths.get(makePath("LOGPATH"));
```

It even seems to to this right, as the ErrorMessage states:

```
SEVERE: /folder1/folder2/logs/thelogIwant.log (No such file or directory)
```

The logfile is being created by another application and therefore in another directory than the .jar I am running.

The path exists on my VPS and I can navigate to and through it. 
Can someone point me in the right direction? What's going wrong here?

Things I tried:

1. Specify path with "~/folder1/..."
2. Specify path with "folder1/..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few possible explanations:

1. The pathname in your config file is wrong; e.g. there is a typo or some other discrepancy that you didn't notice.
2. You are loading a different property file to the one that you think.
3. There is a mismatch between the property name in the file and the name that your tool uses.
4. The other application didn't create the log file
5. Permissions: your tool may be running as a user that isn't permitted to read one of the directories on the path.
6. SELinux in enforcing mode can prevent an application (e.g. running as a service) from accessing files.
7. Homoglyphs, either in the property file<sup>1</sup>, your source code or the name of the file in the file system.

The things that you tried are unlikely to work.  A correct absolute pathname is more *robust* than a relative pathname, and `Paths.get` doesn't know how to deal with `~`.  (The expansion of `~` is a shell feature ....)

---

I would try this:

- Modify your tool to output the value of the "LOGPATH" property ... enclosed in quote characters so that you can see any spurious whitespace characters at the beginning / end of the value.
- Run the tool.
- Using copy-and-paste, see if you can open the file using exactly the pathname that your tool uses.

In short, verify that the pathname you are actually using is what you expect it to be.

---

<sup>1 - In practice, classic format property files are encoded in LATIN-1, so this is impossible.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! A few things: I run the jar as the same user that has the folder1/... in his home directory. The logfile exists and as the same user I can edit it with nano or vim, so permissions should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this, thanks @Steven for your help!

I used the pwd command when in the directory the files are in and recognized that the true absolute path starts with /home/myusername/folder1/...

Works fine now.